# Exporting variation of a class

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to export some variation of a class that I want to import somewhere else.
I don't know it is possible to create them without instantiation? 
And how I can do that.

This is what I have now

*index.ts*

```js
export { Character } from './Character';
```

*Character.ts*

```js
import { CharacterOptions, WarlockOptions } from './CharacterOptions';

class Character implements CharacterInterface {
  private health: number;
  private name: string;
  private characterOptions: CharacterOptions;

  constructor(name, health) {
    this.name = name;
    this.health = health;
    this.characterOptions = new WarlockOptions(); // where WarlockOptions extends CharacterOptions
  }
}
```

I would like to be able to do something like that in the *index.ts* file

```js
import { Character } from './Character';
import { ArcherOptions, WarlockOptions } from './CharacterOptions';

export const ArcherClass = someWrapperOfCharacter(ArcherOptions);
export const WarlockClass = someWrapperOfCharacter(WarlockOptions);
```

like dynamically creating (through `someWrapperOfCharacter()`) a new specific class that I can expose.

I know that I could create directly classes that extend `Character` but I try to avoid that because:

- I don't know how many `CharacterOptions` I will have in the future
- I would like not to be forced to create a new variation each time I want to add a new `CharacterOptions`
- I want to allow to create directly a custom class by passing a custom object that extends `CharacterOptions`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried Titian answer but it didn't satisfied me completely (although it helped me a lot).

I finally wrote the wrapper like this:

```js
interface CharacterInterface { }

class CharacterOptions { public level?: number }
class ArcherOptions extends CharacterOptions { public bow?: string; }
class WarlockOptions extends CharacterOptions { public magic?: string }

export const someWrapperOfCharacter = (optionsCtor: CharacterOptions) => {
  return class Character implements CharacterInterface {
    private health: number;
    private name: string;
    private characterOptions: CharacterOptions;

    constructor(name: string, health: number) {
      this.name = name;
      this.health = health;
      this.characterOptions = new optionsCtor(); 
    }
  }
};

export const ArcherClass = someWrapperOfCharacter(ArcherOptions);
export type ArcherClass = InstanceType<typeof ArcherClass> // needed to allow type declarations let a: ArcherClass

export const WarlockClass = someWrapperOfCharacter(WarlockOptions);
export type WarlockClass = InstanceType<typeof WarlockClass>

const archer = new ArcherClass('archie', 100);
console.log(archer instanceof ArcherClass); // true

const warlock = new WarlockClass('warlie', 100);
console.log(warlock instanceof WarlockClass); // true
```

Answer (score 2):

You could pass in the constructor for options to the class, and have a function that creates derived types that set the options class to a specific implementation:

```
interface CharacterInterface { }

class CharacterOptions { public level?: number }
class ArcherOptions extends CharacterOptions { public bow?: string; }
class WarlockOptions extends CharacterOptions { public magic?: string }


class Character<T extends CharacterOptions> implements CharacterInterface {
    private health: number;
    private name: string;
    private characterOptions: T;

    constructor(name: string, health: number, optionsCtor: new () => T) {
        this.name = name;
        this.health = health;
        this.characterOptions = new optionsCtor(); // where WarlockOptions extends CharacterOptions
    }
}
function someWrapperOfCharacter<T extends CharacterOptions>(optionsCtor: new () => T) {
    return class extends Character<T> {
        constructor(name: string, health: number) {
            super(name, health, optionsCtor);
        }
    }
}

export const ArcherClass = someWrapperOfCharacter(ArcherOptions);
export type ArcherClass = InstanceType<typeof ArcherClass> // needed to allow type declarations let a: ArcherClass

export const WarlockClass = someWrapperOfCharacter(WarlockOptions);
export type WarlockClass = InstanceType<typeof WarlockClass>
```